# Unable to set focus to shinyBS when using rhandsontable

Tags: rhandsontable, shinybs

I have a rhandsontable object within a bsModal with default context menu options. When I right click on a table cell, the context menu options are shown behind the bsModal window, i.e., area not in focus, making it unusable. I would want to have the context menu shown over the bsModal. Is this a limitation? Am I doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic issue related to bsModal and not specific to rHandsontable. Found the solution here [Trouble Adding DatePicker to Modal - Displays in backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063191/trouble-adding-datepicker-to-modal-displays-in-backdrop/24063481#24063481)